How to check which auth scheme was used for current request
I need to implement different logic depending on which auth scheme was used to authenticate the users. Currently i'm using IAuthenticateResultFeature feature on the HttpContext, but i'm having a really hard time with unit testing it. Plus it doesn't really sit well with me since the whole code to get it is:
CurrentAuthScheme = context.HttpContext
    .Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>()?
    .AuthenticateResult?
    .Ticket?.AuthenticationScheme;

And it doesn't really work all that well, because it just returns what is passed to the authorization attribute, not the actual scheme which was used. So if i use for example:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme1,Scheme2")]

This code will return Scheme1,Scheme2, which is absolutely not ideal if i ever need to have multiple schemes on an endpoint.
Is there any way of actually checking which auth scheme was used for the request? Any modifications to ClaimsPrincipal or anything allowed, just to know which scheme was actually used.

Are you using Policies when you setup authorization? Policies can require a particular authentication scheme.

I am not, though i don't see how this would help. The whole gist here is that in theory i can have an endpoint which will be authorized by multiple schemes, and i need to know which one specifically authenticated the request

this is .net 9 and i am getting AuthenticationTypes.Federation when accessing context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType. how did you manage to solve this? why authenticated user is not authenticated by any of my defined schemes!

In the controller, you can retrieve the current used authentication scheme by the following
User.Identity.AuthenticationType

or through the HttpContext
HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType


This is not in the controller. I'm using an IHttpContextAccessor and the value of this property context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType is AuthenticationTypes.Federation for me. And this definitely does not match the auth scheme i'm using

@Animu IHttpContextAccessor should also give you the correct Authentication scheme. Could you check if you registered your authentication scheme? services.AddAuthentication().AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyAuthSchemeHandler>("Scheme1", null).AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, MyAnotherAuthSchemeHandler>("Scheme2",null);

i did registered it under separate names and all. Authentication works absolutely fine for both variants. The only issue is detecting which one is currently in use

@Animu In your AuthenticationHandler, did you create like this
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
I'm %100 sure this is the right way to retrieve

no, i did not because this is not an authentication flow itself. I do not need to create these objects myself, but rather check deep in the app which auth flow was used. This is basically some SomeRandomService with a WhichAuthSchemeWasUsed() method

Well, if your AuthenticationHandler doesn't implement proper AuthenticateResult, then you can't get it in your service. When you specify multiple authentication schemes, it iterates Authentication handlers for specified schemes, and whenever it passes, it will create AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket): The Scheme must be specified in the ticket.

I never said anything about auth handler. I don't implement anything like it. Auth comes literally out of the box from MS and that's it. The ONLY concern is how to get the CURRENT auth scheme in the request.
